# Error: "Could NOT find OpenMP_C" when install LightGBM on MacOS

Tags: macos, cmake, lightgbm

While installing LightGBM on Mac OS, I got the following error:

```
CMake Error at /usr/local/Cellar/cmake/3.12.4/share/cmake/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:137 (message):
  Could NOT find OpenMP_C (missing: OpenMP_C_FLAGS OpenMP_C_LIB_NAMES)
Call Stack (most recent call first): 
  /usr/local/Cellar/cmake/3.12.4/share/cmake/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:378 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
  /usr/local/Cellar/cmake/3.12.4/share/cmake/Modules/FindOpenMP.cmake:466 (find_package_handle_standard_args)
  CMakeLists.txt:82 (find_package)
```

[image]

I am following the official manual, the error comes at `cmake ..` step:

[image]

Thank you for your help if you can help me.

Comment: The error message is about missing OpenMP support. Are you sure that you have performed step `brew install libomp`?

Comment: Yes ,I'm sure done it ! but I still fail ! I try to solve the problem by the information ——'OpenMP_C'

Comment: My ability is limited, don't know how to solve the 'OpenMP_C' problem.

Comment: Please, add the error message into the question post as **text**, not as image. It is a requirement of the Stack Overflow.

Comment: CMake Error at /usr/local/Cellar/cmake/3.12.4/share/cmake/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:137 (message):
  Could NOT find OpenMP_C (missing: OpenMP_C_FLAGS OpenMP_C_LIB_NAMES)
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /usr/local/Cellar/cmake/3.12.4/share/cmake/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:378 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
  /usr/local/Cellar/cmake/3.12.4/share/cmake/Modules/FindOpenMP.cmake:466 (find_package_handle_standard_args)
  CMakeLists.txt:82 (find_package)

Comment: this is the information . I'm sorry I didn't do it before.

Comment: I am having a similar issue, please let me know if you figure out how to fix this.

Answer (score 4):

The solution from the [Darts installation guide](https://github.com/unit8co/darts/blob/master/INSTALL.md#macos-issues-with-lightgbm) worked for me. You need to downgrade the libomp library:

```
wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/fb8323f2b170bd4ae97e1bac9bf3e2983af3fdb0/Formula/libomp.rb
brew unlink libomp
brew install libomp.rb
```